# How to Validate Facebook LoginSession in iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I am implementing Facebook login in my iOS App.

I need to know how to retrieve `ifLoginSession` is currently valid or not .

In latest `FacebookSDK FBSession` class is no more used, therefore we cannot use `FBSession.activeSession` property.

So I have written my code to validate session as

```
- (BOOL)isSessionValid
{

    return ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken])?YES:NO;

}
```

Is it correct way to implement session validity? or am i missing something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In  `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` always update the token and then check its not nil or not

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
[FBSDKProfile enableUpdatesOnAccessTokenChange:YES];
return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}
```

Then u can check like this

```
if (![FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
   //session invalid
} else {
     //session valid
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this code. Based on Facebook SDK version 4.0. It is modified in 4.0 when compared with the older version.

In `App delegate.m`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                          openURL:url
                                                sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                       annotation:annotation];
}
```

In `viewController.m` file

```
- (IBAction)btnFacebookPressed:(id)sender {
    FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
    [login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"email"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error)
     {
         if (error)
         {
             // Process error
         }
         else if (result.isCancelled)
         {
             // Handle cancellations
         }
         else
         {
             if ([result.grantedPermissions containsObject:@"email"])
             {
                 NSLog(@"result is:%@",result);
                 [self fetchUserInfo];
             }
         }
     }];
}

-(void)fetchUserInfo
{
    if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken])
    {
        NSLog(@"Token is available : %@",[[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]tokenString]);

        [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:@{@"fields": @"id, name, link, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email, birthday, bio ,location ,friends ,hometown , friendlists"}]
         startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
             if (!error)
             {
                 NSLog(@"resultis:%@",result);
             }
             else
             {
                 NSLog(@"Error %@",error);
             }
         }];

    }

}
```

In `viewdidload` method call this function `fetchUserInfo`

```
[self fetchUserInfo];
```

By calling this method you will get the access token after login